# fill_between only filling between two x values, not filling entire scatter graph, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to fill between two lines on my scatter graph. This is to show the standard deviation around a mean value of a scatter diagram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y1 # is the first set of y-axis data
y2 # is the second set of y-axis data
y3 # is the third set of y-axis data
x # is the x-axis data set

ym1 = np.mean(y1)
ym2 = np.mean(y2)
ym3 = np.mean(y3)
# To set up the means of the three data series

sigma1 = np.std(y1)
sigma2 = np.std(y2)
sigma3 = np.std(y3)
# To set up the standard deviations

ysupper1 = ym1 + sigma1
ysupper2 = ym2 + sigma2
ysupper3 = ym3 + sigma3
yslower1 = ym1 - sigma1
yslower2 = ym2 - sigma2
yslower3 = ym3 - sigma3
# To set up the higher and lower limits to fill between

yma1 = np.array([ym1])
yma2 = np.array([ym2])
yma3 = np.array([ym3])
# To set up values to put into a plt.axhline
```

After these are set up I create a graph of y1, y2, and y3 against x and no problems occur here. I then set up `plt.axhline`'s and the `plt.fill_between`'s:

```
plt.axhline(yma1, linestyle='--', color='b', alpha=0.7),
plt.axhline(yma2, linestyle='--', color='r', alpha=0.7),
plt.axhline(yma3, linestyle='--', color='c', alpha=0.7),
# To create the 'mean value' lines on the graph

plt.fill_between(x, ysupper1, yslower1, color='b', alpha=0.3),
plt.fill_between(x, ysupper2, yslower2, color='r', alpha=0.3),
plt.fill_between(x, ysupper3, yslower3, color='c', alpha=0.3),
# To fill in between the upper and lower limits of the standard deviation
```

However, the graph that this creates always only has a fill between two points along the x-axis. I have tried manually stating the `where` argument in `plt.fill_between` to be `None` and as I expected nothing changed. I am at a loss as to why it is only filling between these to seemingly arbitrary points along the x-axis. For reference here is an image of the graphs I am getting:

[image: Image of graph that I am getting]

Edit: The answer was found as as always it was because of a failure to understand exactly how a function works.

Comment: Think of `fill_between` as being almost the same as `plot`, except with two lines at ones, with the same `x`-data. I guess from there you can progress independently.

Comment: Is your x's range is your x-axis's range? I guess your x only cover the filled  part of your graph

Comment: The code from the question seems to work correctly, so in order to get help, you should (as always) provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: @heyu91 God I hate making stupid mistakes. I've used `glob.glob` to help sort out the massive amount of files I've used. This means that the values in `x` are not ascending or descending. They are actually going from two arbitrary values extracted from the files due to how `glob.glob` works. It is now working fine after I've used the `np.sort` function to sort `x` into ascending order. I guess that means more changing of the code. I'll make an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem that I found was due to a part of the code I did not mention as I thought it wasn't necessary. I use the `glob.glob` function to help sort the large number of files I access to extract the data I need. While this is fine for normal plotting when using the [np.fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) function the the `x` array simply uses the first and last values in the array to set up the range. This is why I was getting a weird fill range. When I used the `np.sort` to sort `x` into ascending order then used this new array in `np.fill_between` it then worked. Sorry for the clutter.